# Is it okay to create a DTO counterpart of a table in a database assuming its persistent ignorant domain model and the DTO is in the repository?

Tags: java, c#, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

What prompted me to ask this question is that my class for example Invoice has private fields and i dont want to use its setters because some does calculations of some sort. instead my options are: all fields in constructor or reflection to reconstitute the object from the database (which occurs in the repository layer(repository pattern))

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a separate DTO, just use a good ORM framework. Most modern ORM frameworks (such as Hibernate) can map private fields without needing a getter/setter. Yes, they use reflection internally, but you don't have to write any of that yourself.

Comment: Thank you!! however i am currently using Dapper as my ORM because I find entity framework slow and has a lot of overhead. I will try this with dapper. Again thank you for your opinion.